# How can I extract audio from video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried the following command to extract audio from video:

```
ffmpeg -i Sample.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 Sample.mp3
```

but I get the following output

```
libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
SamplE.avi: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 890):

To extract the audio stream without re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input-video.avi -vn -acodec copy output-audio.aac
```

- `-vn` is no video.
- `-acodec copy` says use the same audio stream that's already in there.

Read the output to see what codec it is, to set the right filename extension.

Comment: If you only extract audio from a video stream, the length of the audio may be shorter than the length of the video. To make sure this doesn't happen, extract both audio AND video with the same call to ffmpeg, e.g. "ffmpeg -i vid.avi -map 0:a audio.wav -map 0:v onlyvideo.avi

Comment: It would be great to expand this answer with a command that also encapsulates the raw AAC into a M4A container.

Comment: In this precise case, just replace ".aac" with ".m4a" in the destination path. ffmpeg is smart enough to guess your intent, and it encapsulates the result into an M4A container :)

Comment: FWIW, I have crafted a PHP script, so that I just specify the input video file, and it automatically determines the extension of the output audio file: https://superuser.com/questions/1301901/ffmpeg-how-to-determine-output-extension-automatically-ca-copy/1336570#1336570

Comment: `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'acodec'`... Opps that was due to `acodec` instead of `-acodec`.

Comment: @FlorianB how is running ffmpeg an issue? Isn't `ffmpeg` without output argument an alias for `ffprobe` anyway?

Comment: incredibly fast! in my case: `size=16713kB time=00:23:08.13 bitrate=98.6kbits/s speed=2.2e+03x
video:0kB audio:16268kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.734343%`

Comment: Does someone have an idea of how to do using c API?

Comment: Or if you prefer MP3 where size matters use: `ffmpeg -i inputVid.avi -b:a 192k outputAu.mp3`

Comment: I have an opposite issue. I ran `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01:57 -c copy -t 00:51:05 output.mp4` but output was only audio? I also tried output.avi, same thing. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up needing to change the order of the arguments to get the video. I used `ffmpeg -ss 00:01:57 -i input.mp4 -t 00:51:05 -c copy output.mp4` and it worked great (took only a few seconds). I don't have an explanation as to why I needed to change the order from @Paul Irish's answer

Comment: To quote superuser.com: The basic command is: ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 filename.mp3
Only -i flag is necessary. Just tested it ... also works with .ts to .aac

Comment: @paul-irish: Does this method by any chance change the audio length from the video length? I saw Jeremy's answer here and I got an audio with length `1min 2 seconds` - whereas video was only `1 minutes` - I don't want that, since later on I want to merge the audio back to a modified video

Answer (score 415):

To encode a high quality MP3 or MP4 audio from a movie file (eg AVI, MP4, MOV, etc) or audio file (eg WAV), I find it's best to use `-q:a 0` for variable bit rate and it's good practice to specify `-map a` to exclude video/subtitles and only grab audio:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.avi -q:a 0 -map a sample.mp3
```

If you want to **extract a portion of audio from a video** use the `-ss` option to specify the starting timestamp, and the `-t` option to specify the encoding duration, eg from 3 minutes and 5 seconds in for 45 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.avi -ss 00:03:05 -t 00:00:45.0 -q:a 0 -map a sample.mp3
```

- The timestamps need to be in HH:MM:SS.xxx format or in seconds.
- If you don't specify the **-t** option it will go to the end.
- You can use the **-to** option instead of the **-t** option, if you want to specify the range, eg for 45 seconds: `00:03:05 + 45 = 00:03:50`

**Working example:**

1. Download [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)
2. Open a Command Prompt (Start > Run > CMD) or on a Mac/Linux open a Terminal
3. cd (the change directory command) to the directory with the ffmeg.exe, as depicted.
4. Issue your command and wait for the output file (or troubleshoot any errors)

**Windows**
[image]

**Mac/Linux**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Here's a guide for the `-q:a` values: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3 Zero is the highest-quality VBR setting, which typically results in average bitrates in the upper part of the sane CBR range (where 320 kbit/s is the maximum, probably a bit beyond the point at which lossless compression becomes more appropriate).

Comment: And what does `-map a` do?

Comment: Caveat: this is re-encoding the audio with a lossy compression, which will degrade quality slightly. If the original is already compressed, you will degrade the quality twice, which may or may not be noticeable.

Comment: This command works for me, when the one above with `-vn` does not.

Comment: Re-encoding is not extraction, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Bachsau I clearly explain its variable bit rate re-encoding and my answer also addressed extracting portions. 130 people benefitted (with enough rep to vote) from this answer so far and you're welcome to post your own answer.

Comment: I want to get .mp3 file from .mp4 file ,use the cmd ，it worked, detail:
 `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -q:a 0 -map a novideo.mp3`

Comment: @IulianOnofrei `-map a` includes audio only.

Answer (score 137):

## Extract all audio tracks / streams

This puts all audio into one file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0:a -c copy output.mov
```

- `-map 0:a` selects **all** audio streams only. Video and subtitles will be excluded.
- `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. This copies the audio and does not re-encode it. Remove `-c copy` if you want the audio to be re-encoded.
- Choose an output format that supports your audio format. See [comparison of container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Audio_coding_formats_support).

---

## Extract a specific audio track / stream

Example to extract audio stream #4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:a:3 -c copy output.m4a
```

- `-map 0:a:3` selects audio stream #4 only (`ffmpeg` starts counting from 0).
- `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. This copies the audio and does not re-encode it. Remove `-c copy` if you want the audio to be re-encoded.
- Choose an output format that supports your audio format. See [comparison of container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Audio_coding_formats_support).

---

## Extract and re-encode audio / change format

Similar to the examples above, but without `-c copy`. Various examples:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:a output.mp3
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:a output.m4a
ffmpeg -i input.avi -map 0:a -c:a aac output.mka
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.wav
```

---

## Extract all audio streams individually

This input in this example has 4 audio streams. Each audio stream will be output as single, individual files.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0:a:0 output0.wav -map 0:a:1 output1.wav -map 0:a:2 output2.wav -map 0:a:3 output3.wav
```

Optionally add `-c copy` before each output file name to enable [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode.

---

## Extract a certain channel

Use the [channelsplit filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit). Example to get the Front Right (FR) channel from a stereo input:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FR[right]" -map "[right]" front_right.wav
```

- `channel_layout` is the channel layout of the input. It is not automatically detected so you must provide the layout name.
- `channels` lists the channel(s) you want to extract.
- See `ffmpeg -layouts` for audio channel layout names (for `channel_layout`) and channel names (for `channels`).
- Using [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (`-c copy`) is not possible to use when filtering, so the audio must be re-encoded.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for more examples.

---

### What's the difference between `-map` and `-vn`?

`ffmpeg` has a default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior that will select 1 stream per stream type (1 video, 1 audio, 1 subtitle, 1 data).

`-vn` is an old, legacy option. It excludes video from the default stream selection behavior. So audio, subtitles, and data are still automatically selected unless told not to with `-an`, `-sn`, or `-dn`.

`-map` is more complicated but more flexible and useful. `-map` disables the default stream selection behavior and `ffmpeg` will only include what you tell it to with `-map` option(s). `-map` can also be used to exclude certain streams or stream types. For example, `-map 0 -map -0:v` would include all streams **except** all video.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more examples.

---

### Errors

#### Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.

MP3 only supports 1 audio stream. The error means you are trying to put more than 1 audio stream into MP3. It can also mean you are trying to put non-MP3 audio into MP3.

#### WAVE files have exactly one stream

Similar to above.

#### Could not find tag for codec in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container

You are trying to put an audio format into an output that does not support it, such as PCM (WAV) into MP4.

Remove `-c copy`, choose a different output format (change the file name extension), or manually choose the encoder (such as `-c:a aac`).

See [comparison of container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Audio_coding_formats_support).

#### Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

This is a useless, generic error. The actual, informative error should immediately precede this generic error message.

Comment: How do you do the "Extract all audio streams individually" case, when you don't know exactly how many audio streams there are? I need a generalizable way to extract all audio streams individually.

Answer (score 72):

Seems like you're extracting audio from a video file & downmixing to stereo channel. 
To just extract audio (without re-encoding):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vn -c:a copy out.m4a
```

To extract audio & [downmix to stereo](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a5.1stereo) (without re-encoding):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vn -c:a copy -ac 2 out.m4a
```

To generate an mp3 file, you'd re-encode audio:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vn -ac 2 out.mp3
```

**`-c` (*select codecs*) & `-map` (*select streams*) options:**

`-c:a` -> select best supported audio (transcoded)
`-c:a copy` -> best supported audio (copied)
`-map 0:a` -> all audio from 1st (audio) input file (transcoded)
`-map 0:0` -> 1st stream from 1st input file (transcoded)
`-map 1:a:0` -> 1st audio stream from 2nd (audio) input file (transcoded)
`-map 1:a:1 -c:a copy` -> 2nd audio stream from 2nd (audio)input file (copied)

Comment: You can't downmix (or make any other alteration) without re-encoding.

Comment: This extracts just the first audio track. How could I extract the 2nd?  (Or all of them, to separate files?)

Comment: @PhilGoetz: for 2nd audio/stream in 1st input file: `-map 0:a:1`

Answer (score 13):

`ffmpeg -i sample.avi` will give you the audio/video format info for your file. Make sure you have the proper libraries configured to parse the input streams. Also, make sure that the file isn't corrupt.

Comment: now,i got correct result when i tried the same comment with a .mkv vedio.why it is not working for .avi,is there any ffmpeg command to convert .avi

Comment: AVI or MKV refers to the container format which can hold lots of different audio/video formats. You are not looking to convert AVI audio, you are looking to convert the audio track within the AVI file, which you haven't specified as of yet. Use the command I listed above to see what kind of audio track is within the AVI file. 
If it is MP3 you'll need to compile FFMPEG with an MP3 library like LAME http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 12):

The command line is correct and works on a valid video file. I would make sure that you have installed the correct library to work with mp3, install lame o probe with another audio codec.

Usually

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

or

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

would give sufficient information so that you know more.

Answer (score 11):

To encode mp3 audio [ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) shows the following example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 output.mp3
```

I extracted the audio from a video just by replacing `input.wav` with the video filename. The `2` means 190 kb/sec. You can see the other quality levels at my link above.

Comment: That example is for converting an audio file to a different format, not to extract it from a video.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, as I described in my answer, you can replace the audio file with a video file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

For people looking for the simpler way to extract audio from a video file while retaining the original video file's parameters, you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i <video_file_name.extension> <audio_file_name.extension>
```

For example, running:

```
ffmpeg -i screencap.mov screencap.mp3
```

extracts an `mp3` audio file from a `mov` video file.

Comment: Simple and works.  Why are all the other solutions so complicated?  +1

Comment: The question is, why does this have a delete vote?!

Comment: exactly, this works for me every time. Why is it not the best answer yet?

Comment: @SMBiggs: because this re-encodes the audio, losing quality.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, Could a video file contain MP3 audio? And if yes, does this command re-encodes the audio in this case too?

Comment: @DanDascalescu  Didn't know that--thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I just used:

```
ffmpeg -i my.mkv -map 0:3 -vn -b:a 320k my.mp3
```

Options explanation:

- my.mkv is a source video file, you can use other formats as well
- `-map 0:3` means I want 3rd stream from video file. Put your N there - video files often has multiple audio streams; you can omit it or use `-map 0:a` to take the default audio stream. Run `ffprobe my.mkv` to see what streams does the video file have.
- my.mp3 is a target audio filename, and ffmpeg figures out I want an MP3 from its extension. In my case the source audio stream is ac3 DTS and just copying wasn't what I wanted
- 320k is a desired target bitrate
- -vn means I don't want video in target file

Answer (score 6):

## Creating an audio book from several video clips

1. First, extracting the audio (as `.m4a) from a bunch of h264 files:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -c:a copy "$(basename "$f" .mp4).m4a"; done
```

> the `-vn` output option disables video output (automatic selection or mapping of any video stream). For [full manual control](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) see the `-map` option.

### Optional

2. If there's an intro of, say, 40 seconds, you can skip it with the `-ss` parameter:

```
for f in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -ss 00:00:40  -c copy crop/"$f"; done
```

3. To combine all files in one:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.m4a; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.m4a
```

Answer (score 2):

If the audio wrapped into the avi is not mp3-format to start with, you may need to specify `-acodec mp3` as an additional parameter.  Or whatever your mp3 codec is (on Linux systems its probably `-acodec libmp3lame`).  You may also get the same effect, platform-agnostic, by instead specifying `-f mp3` to "force" the format to mp3, although not all versions of ffmpeg still support that switch.  Your Mileage May Vary.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-b:a` instead of `-ab` as `-ab` is outdated now, also make sure your input file path is correct.

To extract audio from a video I have used below command and its working fine.

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", inputFileAbsolutePath, "-vn", "-ar", "44100", "-ac", "2", "-b:a", "256k", "-f", "mp3", outputFileAbsolutePath};
```

Here,

- `-y` - Overwrite output files without asking.
- `-i` - FFmpeg reads from an arbitrary number of input “files” specified by the `-i` option
- `-vn` - Disable video recording
- `-ar` - sets the sampling rate for audio streams if encoded
- `-ac` - Set the number of audio channels.
- `-b:a` - Set the audio bitrate
- `-f` - format

Check out [**this**](https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android) for my complete sample FFmpeg android project on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

To extract without conversion I use a context menu entry - as file manager custom action in Linux - to run the following (after having checked what audio type the video contains; example for video containing `ogg` audio):

```
bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0:a -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".ogg' %f
```

which is based on the ffmpeg command `ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0:a -c:a copy OUTPUT`.

I have used `-map 0:1` in that without problems, but, as said in a comment by  @LordNeckbeard, *"Stream `0:1` is not guaranteed to always be audio. Using `-map 0:a` instead of `-map 0:1` will avoid ambiguity."*

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  ~ I will take that into account, thanks.

Comment: I used `mediainfo` to determine the audio track, and chose it like this: `-map 0:a:1` where a:1 is the second audio track index, thx! `-c:a copy` made it much faster!