# Disable Video area in the MediaElement in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I am playing a Video url in the MediaElement in one of my WPF application. But I have to play only Audio and dont need to display any video area in the MediaElement. It needs to be disabled. Is there any option to do this ?. Can you guys help me in this ?

Comment: Would setting both the height and width of the MediaElement to 0 suffice? Feels kludgy at best but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just convert the video to a sound file? I would also use the windows forms media element over the WPF due to it's flexibility and ability to handle poor quality video's better.

Comment: I dont want any process of converting Video to Audio file as I am already doing heavy update while setting PlaySource so can you please help me in this ?

Comment: I would argue for saving the audio out to its own file, which is not the same thing as converting the video. FFmpeg will do this for multiple hour videos in a second or two - see Paul Irish's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913032/ffmpeg-to-extract-audio-from-video . The reduction in overhead of playing back an audio file versus a video file may be substantial.