# Bento4 MP4Dash fails with audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, bento

I am running Bento4 Mp4Dash to convert my fragmented video files into MPEG-DASH streaming videos. However I seem to get this error

> ERROR: unsupported input file, more than one "traf" box in fragment

but only if I have audio enabled. I have found that if I run -an in FFMPEG (to ignore the audio tracks) my MP4Dash command runs just fine, any ideas as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by telling ffmpeg to extract the audio from the file I wanted to convert to DASH. Here is my solution in case someone still needs them.

- extract audio
- generate second video file with no audio
- tell Bento4 Mp4Dash to use the video and the audio

For all steps there are tons of explainations how to do it on the internet. Here are some I found:

- extract audio with the `-vn` flag, [ffmpeg to extract audio from video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913032/ffmpeg-to-extract-audio-from-video)
- video without audio with the `-an` flag, [Remove audio from video file with FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/268985/remove-audio-from-video-file-with-ffmpeg)
- tell Bento4 to use them each by following the advice in [the official Usage documentation](https://www.bento4.com/developers/dash/), section Advanced usage: add both the video and audio file as input and add `[type=video]` before the video and `[type=audio]` before the audio file (no space in between)