# Merge audio and video in c#?

Tags: c#, audio, video

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to merge and audio and a video file in C#. So far, everything I've found online is not what I'm looking for, and I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible.

Comment: What like this: https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg You can start ffmpeg with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

Comment: I've tried that. I asked a question about it but no one answered :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584389/combine-audio-and-video-files-with-ffmpeg-in-c-sharp

Comment: You should have mentioned the duplicate. This is pretty much the same question only broader  and you've been here a few years now... Try the exact FFMPEG arguments in the SU answer I linked to as that worked for all those people.

Comment: To be fair, I made this account like my freshman year of high school and just started using it again

Comment: Yeah but the same question in 2 days... your other question is better. Lets loop it back.