# How to get audio samples from python-VLC

Tags: python, vlc, pydub, python-vlc

## What I need

I am working on a music player with a sample analyzer. My issue is that I am currently using pydub to get the samples from the song, but as the song gets longer, the more out of sync the two become. I have made the two literally in sync, pydub just so happens to read out of it [I even started them at the same time, the two actually progressively de-synced with audio alone and more so as the song continues playing].

Basically, is there a python-vlc equivalent to `pydub.AudioSegment.get_array_of_samples()`?

You can look at the python-vlc docs here: https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/

## What I've tried

1. python-vlc has `sound.get_time()` which returns the last updated time in milliseconds. The issue with this command is not that it only updates every half a second or so [I've found a way around that] but that it doesn't return the accurate time. I can start a timer from when it starts playing using `time.monotonic()`. As time progresses, the `get_time()` wildly varies from the timer. I've gotten a difference of 195ms, 294ms and 217ms.
2. I tried using an external timer using the `threading` module. It appears that `pydub.AudioSegment[index]` is not in sync whatsoever.
3. Scaling from `sound.get_time()` in py-vlc to `len(sound)` in pydub. This doesn't work as expected. I cannot tell you why but it is still desynced.
4. Using `sound.get_time()` with an average offset that increases over time. It appears that `pydub.AudioSegment[index]` doesn't line up properly.
5. Using `aubio`. It only reads WAV files, and for a live analyzer, converting to a WAV first would take too long.

## Things I found out

- I've looked at how long each song is in milliseconds, `len(sound)` for pydub and `sound.get_length()` for python-vlc is different usually by 10 or so seconds.

## Things that won't work

- Using pydub's `play()` command. I don't like it because it's very limiting.
- Using something else than py-vlc to play the audio, VLC has many features that just cannot be replicated.

## Previous suggestions

- Use [How can I extract audio from video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913032/how-can-i-extract-audio-from-video-with-ffmpeg)

  - This won't work because I am not looking to extract audio from an existing video file, I'm trying to get samples like `pydub.AudioSegment.get_array_of_samples()`

## I'm curious

- Is there a python module for Audacity? I've been looking and couldn't find it. I can also use some other command line tool that can interact with Audacity if possible [I know the built in command line utility doesn't do much at all]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use ffmpeg directly for this.

Comment: How can I use it? I know I can use `subprocess.run([...], capture_output = True)` but what command in ffmpeg do I use?

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913032/how-can-i-extract-audio-from-video-with-ffmpeg maybe

Comment: I'm not trying to extract audio, I'm trying to get audio sample data like `pydub.AudioSegment.get_array_of_samples()`. I'm already working with audio files anyway.