# Use ffmpeg with paths in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, local-storage

I have no idea how to use ffmpeg from paths. In all the examples I have seen use files from assets, and this solution does not apply to my problem.

This is an example that is in another question here: [How to extract audio from video using ffmpeg-kit with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75369875/how-to-extract-audio-from-video-using-ffmpeg-kit-with-flutter)

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getAudio();
  }

  getAudio() async {
    await FFmpegKit.execute(
            "ffmpeg -i D:/Dart and Flutter/Projects/Jmm/firebase_task/assets/videos/flutter.mp4 -q:a 0 -map a D:/Dart and Flutter/Projects/Jmm/firebase_task/assets/videos/flutter_audio.mp3")
        .then((value) async {
      var returnCode = await value.getReturnCode();
      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
        print('succsses');
      } else {
        print('fail');
      }
    });
  }
```

but, again, they convert the files from assets.

I hope you can help, thank you very much

I tried to adapt the solution that they apply in the link provided, and I expected to have an audio file, but, this did not happen